# How to delete Vue.js component image from Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-storage, vuetify.js

I am building a Vue.js component that enables uploading and deleting of images on Firebase. So far, my component enables uploading images to database and storage. The image can be deleted only from the database, but still remains in storage. To resolve this, I have attempted to set up the `deleteImg()`function with a `.then()`promise to target images in storage for deleting. The example in the docs ('https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files') is setup to target a hard-coded image. How can I set my delete function to remove specific images targeted by a delete button? Here is my delete function:

```
    deleteImg(img) {
      db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()
      .then(() => {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var desertRef = storageRef.child('images/Desert.jpg');
        desertRef.delete().then(function() {
          console.log('Document successfully deleted')
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getImages()
      })
    }
```

Here is entire component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app-bar color="indigo" dark fixed app>
      <v-toolbar-title>Vue Firebase Image Upload</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-content>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
              <img :src="imageUrl" height="150" v-if="imageUrl" />
              <v-text-field label="Select Image" @click="pickFile" v-model="imageName"></v-text-field>
              <input type="file" style="display: none" ref="image" accept="image/*" @change="onFilePicked"/>
              <v-btn color="primary" @click="upload">UPLOAD</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
          <br />

          <v-layout align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
              <div v-for="img in imgUrls" :key="img.id">
                <br />
                <img :src="img.downloadUrl" height="150" />
                <v-btn @click="deleteImg(img.id)">x</v-btn>
              </div>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { db } from "./main";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      photo: null,
      photo_url: null,
      dialog: false,
      imageName: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      imageFile: "",
      imgUrls: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getImages();
  },
  methods: {
    getImages: function() {
      db.collection("images")
        .get()
        .then(snap => {
          const array = [];
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            const data = doc.data()
            array.push({
              id: doc.id,
              ...data
            });
          });
          this.imgUrls = array;
        });
      this.imageName = ""
      this.imageFile = ""
      this.imageUrl = ""
    },
    pickFile() {
      this.$refs.image.click();
    },
    onFilePicked(e) {
      const files = e.target.files;
      if (files[0] !== undefined) {
        this.imageName = files[0].name;
        if (this.imageName.lastIndexOf(".") <= 0) {
          return;
        }
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        fr.addEventListener("load", () => {
          this.imageUrl = fr.result;
          this.imageFile = files[0]; // this is an image file that can be sent to server...
        });
      } else {
        this.imageName = "";
        this.imageFile = "";
        this.imageUrl = "";
      }
    },
    upload: function() {
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      var mountainsRef = storageRef.child(`images/${this.imageName}`);
      mountainsRef.put(this.imageFile).then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
          this.imageUrl = downloadURL;
          const bucketName = "xxx-xxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx";
          const filePath = this.imageName;
          db.collection("images").add({
            downloadURL,
            downloadUrl:
              `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucketName}/o/images` +
              "%2F" +
              `${encodeURIComponent(filePath)}?alt=media`,
            originalName: this.imageName,
            timestamp: Date.now()
          });
          this.getImages();
        });
      });
    },
    deleteImg(img) {
      db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()
      .then(() => {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var desertRef = storageRef.child('images/Desert.jpg');
        desertRef.delete().then(function() {
          console.log('Document successfully deleted')
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getImages()
      })
    }
  },
  components: {}
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

UPDATED DELETE FUNCTION

```
async deleteImg(img) {
  let imgDBRef = await db.collection("images").doc(img).get()
    let imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null;
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    let desertRef = storageRef.child('images/' + imgFileName);
    desertRef.delete()
    db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()
    this.getImages()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final answer:

```
async deleteImg(img) {
  let imgDBRef = await db.collection("images").doc(img).get()
  let imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null;
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  let desertRef = storageRef.child('images/' + imgFileName);
  await desertRef.delete()
  await db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()
  await this.getImages()
}
```

Comment: A lot of the other answers here are misleading or deprecated. This solution works great! Thanks, @JS_is_awesome18 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to save an image file name to the DB in order to have ability to map it to the storage item.

Add `imageName` from here:

```
storageRef.child(`images/${this.imageName}`);
```

to `db.collection("images").add(..)` function argument object:

```js
db.collection("images").add({
            downloadURL,
            originalName: this.imageName,
          });
```

and then in your `deleteImg` function just get the `originalName` from `db.collection("images").doc(img)` document data something like this:

```js
const imgDBRef = db.collection("images").doc(img).get();
const imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null;
//... here should be your checks for image name nullable state etc.
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const desertRef = storageRef.child('images/' + imgFileName);
```

And it's better to store file names as hashes, not real names.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I incorporated your answer, but the console continually returns the null. I will update my delete function in the answer to show you how I added it. Any recommendations on how to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting a reference by `db.collection("images").doc(img)` code to the image? Try to check that by `console.log` and then if the reference is not null, try to get document values with `originalName`.

Comment: I setup console.log(imgFileName) to see what was being assigned to that imgFileName based on ```let imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null; ```. The console continually returns null, which means imgFileName never actually gets ```originalName```. Is there perhaps another way that you would recommend assigning a reference to imgfileName instead of using a ternary statement?

Comment: Try to replace `let imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null;` to `let imgData = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data() : null;` and then check which fields are at data `console.log(imgData);` We should check, that imgData really contains some fields that you set during upload.

Comment: Thanks again. console.log still returns null for this.

Comment: Try to place `debugger` directive after `const imgDBRef = db.collection("images").doc(img).get();` and check what is in `imgDBRef` variable. We need to extract data from that reference.

Comment: OK I think I'm getting somewhere with this. The data is in that variable according to console. I had another statement inside that same function ```db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()``` that was deleting the data before I could assign it to the variable. That is why it returned null. I fixed this now. Console.log for ```let imgDBRef = db.collection("images").doc(img).get()``` now says that the target data exists. However, what should I do with ```let imgFileName = imgDBRef.exists ? imgDBRef.data().originalName : null;``` in order to trigger a full removal? See my function above.

Comment: OK I think I just figured it all out. See the above updated function. Your approach worked! I think the trick was to set up ```deleteImg() ``` as an async function. So...now the image in storage and the reference in the database both delete without errors. I will update my function above. Let me know if this makes sense. then I'll post a final answer. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Ok so I guess the question now is why does this work? Why did adding async/await to the function make this work all of a sudden? Why could I not just have ```db.collection("images).doc(img).delete()``` in a .then() promise?

Comment: Great! I think that did not work because some promises were racing with one another, so that data did not come to necessary moment. Also I would add `await` before these statements: `await desertRef.delete()` and `await db.collection("images").doc(img).delete()` to be sure that each one is performed, the deletion completed and then load images `this.getImages()` (probably with `await` either)

Answer (score 0):

To delete an image from storage, you'll need to know the path to that image in the Cloud Storage bucket. If you only have the download URL for the image, you can get a reference with [`firebase.storage().refFromUrl(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#ref-fromurl) and then call `delete()` in the result.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the feedback.  I understand how to utilize the storage path in the context of the upload function, but not for the delete function. Could you expand on this a little? I attempted to apply what you said to my ```deleteImg()``` function, but to no avail. See my updated function at the bottom of the answer..

Comment: Your `deleteImg` code looks fine at first glance. What doesn't work about that code? When you step through it in a debugger, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I am getting two errors. First says ```Error in v-on handler: "[object Object] ```. Second is a FirebaseStorageError (see above)

Comment: What doesn't work is deleting from storage. The file path in the database is removed, as well as the image on the screen. But the image still stays in storage. I want that deleted as well.

Comment: So, stepping through the code in the debugger, what [path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#full-path) does `desertRef` point to? Is that indeed the image to remove? If so, does it go into the `then()` or into the `catch()` block after that line?

Comment: ```console.log(desertRef)``` appears to be pointing to the image. The Reference message in the console shows the fullpath pointing to the ID associated with the image, as well as the correct bucketName. However, it still goes to the catch() block after that line. The .then()statement for deleting from storage never fires.

Comment: The reference message that I indicated is based on ```let desertRef = firebase.storage().ref(img);```. .refFromURL does not return anything to the console, so I changed it from ```.refFromURL``` to ```.ref```

Comment: I don't understand, why can't ```console.log(desertRef)``` return a message to the console for ```let desertRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL(img);```?

Comment: If you have the path to the image, you can just all `firebase.storage.ref(pathToImage).delete()`. If you instead have the download URL, my answer should work for you.

Comment: Thanks again. I might not actually be clear on how to retrieve the path to the image. How can I get that for a specific image? Maybe this is the issue, I don't actually know how to setup a call to the image path inside the delete function. Once I have that, then I should be able to assign it to pathToImage and then delete, correct?

Comment: You need to know the path of the image to be able to delete it. If you only know the download URL, you can get the path with the code in my answer. If you know neither the path, nor the download URL, how do you know what image to delete?

Comment: I understand that I need either the path or the download URL in order to know what to delete. I guess what I am struggling with, and maybe this is hard to explain through comments, is that I am not sure how to factor in the function argument when setting up the delete function to target a specific image based on either the path or the download URL. It is my understanding that this delete function also needs an argument, which in this case will be "img". How can I set up your answer to target the path or download URL while also factoring in the argument? Or is that even the right approach?